# dynamically allocating memory to matrices

Tags: c++, matrix

I am trying to convert an array to a matrix, so I dynamically allocated memory to the matrix, but I'm getting an error:

> CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer

```
int main() {

    float a[9] = { 1, 3, 5, 6,4,6,5,6,8};

    int b = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    int r = sqrt(b) - 1;

    float **A_mat = new float*[r];
    //A_mat = ;

    for (int i = 0; i <= r; i++)
        A_mat[i] = new float[r];

    for (int j = 0; j <= r; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= r; i++) {
            A_mat[j][i] = a[i + j * (r+1)];
        }
    }

    cout << "a[0,0] is " << A_mat[0][0] << endl;
    cout << "a[0,2] is " << A_mat[0][2] << endl;
    cout << "a[1,0] is " << A_mat[1][0] << endl;
    cout << "a[2,0] is " << A_mat[2][0] << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i <= r; i++) {
        delete[] A_mat[i];
    }

    delete[] A_mat;

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: This is full of so many small problems. Double check all of your loops.

Comment: An array of `N` elements has indices from 0 to `N-1`

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i <= r; i++)` is wrong. You want `for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)`. Notice the `<` vs the `<=`.

Comment: Sidenote: A flat array such as `a` is often the optimal representation for a dense matrix.

Comment: Consider using `std::vector<std::vector<float>>` instead. You could have used its built-in bounds checking to catch this indexing mistake

Answer (score 0):

Your code has two major issues:

Issue 1:

```
float **A_mat = new float*[r]; // allocating memory for 2 rows because r = sqrt(9) - 1 => r = 2

for (int i = 0; i <= r; i++)
    A_mat[i] = new float[r]; // Usage of A_mat[r] for r = 2 is out of bounds. Also, memory is allocated for 2 columns.
```

Issue 2:

```
for (int j = 0; j <= r; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= r; i++) {
        A_mat[j][i] = a[i + j * (r+1)]; // accessing indices (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2) are out of bounds
    }
}
```

Instead, you should allocate (r + 1) size memory. Like this:

```
int main() {

    float a[9] = { 1, 3, 5, 6,4,6,5,6,8};

    int b = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    int r = sqrt(b) - 1;

    float **A_mat = new float*[r + 1];
    //A_mat = ;

    for (int i = 0; i <= r; i++)
        A_mat[i] = new float[r + 1];

    for (int j = 0; j <= r; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= r; i++) {
            A_mat[j][i] = a[i + j * (r+1)];
        }
    }

    cout << "a[0,0] is " << A_mat[0][0] << endl;
    cout << "a[0,2] is " << A_mat[0][2] << endl;
    cout << "a[1,0] is " << A_mat[1][0] << endl;
    cout << "a[2,0] is " << A_mat[2][0] << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i <= r; i++) {
        delete[] A_mat[i];
    }

    delete[] A_mat;

    system("pause");
}
```

**Suggestions**:

1) Never use raw pointers. Always look for safer alternatives. In this case, you should go for `std::vector`.

2) Never use naked `new`. It is generally the major source of Memory leaks. Though currently, its not the case for you. But it might become an issue in the future.

3) Always remember that array starts from 0-indexing in C++.

Comment: @YoosufAIshaaq Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with for loop. The index is from 0 to (r-1). But your for loop from 0 to r. It made out of bound of your array.

1> So please replace this for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i <= r; i++)
```

by

```
for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
```

2> And replace this statements

```
for (int j = 0; j <= r; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= r; i++) {
        A_mat[j][i] = a[i + j * (r+1)];
    }
}
```

by

```
for (int j = 0; j < r; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        A_mat[j][i] = a[i + j * r];
    }
}
```